# AngularJS Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'fn' is not a function, got string with Google Maps SDK Async Loader

Tags: angularjs, google-maps

Error: [$injector:module] Failed to instantiate module uiGmapgoogle-maps due to:
Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'fn' is not a function, got string

I've tried to add google-maps-api to my angular js project in the main.js (app.js) file, which now looks like this. Unfortunately I get the above error. I'd really appreciate some guidance, I've spent 3 hours trying to fix this and I just can't figure it out. I'm trying to use the SDK Async loader instead of .

```
angular
.module('sfeVendorApp', [
'ngAnimate',
'ngCookies',
'ngResource',
'ngRoute',
'ngSanitize',
'ngTouch',
['google-maps'.ns()]
])
  .config(['GoogleMapApiProvider'.ns()], function ($routeProvider, GoogleMapApi) {
GoogleMapApi.configure({
      key: 'AIzaSyCXxlIQE_baTY18opP79TFol5Ck40xQyP8',
      v: '3.17',
      libraries: 'weather,geometry,visualization'
  }); 
$routeProvider
  .when('/login', {
    templateUrl: 'views/login.html',
    controller: 'LoginCtrl'
  })
  .when('/openshop', {
    templateUrl: 'views/openshop.html',
    controller: 'OpenShopCtrl'

  })
  .when('/about', {
    templateUrl: 'views/about.html',
    controller: 'AboutCtrl'
  })
  .otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/login'
  });

})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this same problem today. I was able to fix it by rearranging the order of the js refrences in the my html.

I have them roughly in this order:

```
<script src="path/bluebird.js"></script>
<script src="path/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="path/angular.js"></script>
<script src="path/lodash.min.js"></script>
<script src="path/angular-google-maps.js"></script>
```

..then my controllers and services.

I used this file as a reference
https://github.com/angular-ui/angular-google-maps/blob/master/example/example.html

Hope this helps.